# Why is this Update function never Called?

Tags: unity

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Mos_Giant : Enemy
{
    public override void update()
    {
        Debug.Log("AAA");
    }

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

C# is case sensitive. Case sensitivity defines whether uppercase and lowercase letters are treated as distinct (case-sensitive) or equivalent (case-insensitive).

That means `update()` is not the same as `Update()`.

Change it to uppercase and it should now be called.